# PHP: preg_replace href if href contains my string

Tags: php, html

I want if my link have name.com, preg_replace to work

```
$string = '<a href="test/name.com/new">a</a>
           <a href="test/your.com/new">b</a>';
           echo $string = preg_replace("/<a\s(.+?)>(.+?)<\/a>/is", "<b>$2</b>", $string);
```

**output**

```
<b>a</b>
<a href="test/your.com/new">b</a>
```

But not work and replace all links

Comment: `/<a\s(.*?)href=".*?name.com.*?".*?>(.+?)<\/a>/`

Comment: But it's better to use html parser, for example, domDocument

Comment: @splash58 thank you. how i can change $2 value ? sample : `$2 = str_replace('w','x',$w);`